# CCK ahah image upload working if admin, but not for others!

Tags: 6, entities, media, ajax

A content type have image field. When uploading image as admin, everything works fine. But If i logged in as a normal user, and click on upload , it gives error ahah http error alert!

Also found add another button also giving same error.

What could be the issue?

Comment: what error comes?

Answer (score 0):

What Drupal version do you use?
May I have list of modules you have?
What messages do you have in watchdog?

First think I have is drupal permission problem.

Comment: i think its D6.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following URL and check if you have given required permissions to the image field.

http://www.your-website.com/admin/user/permissions

If you want the normal user to access the image field, then you have to give required permissions to anonymous user.

Comment: "Also found add another button also giving same error." . So i dont think its permission problem, i have crosschecked permissions. Its something related to ahah!

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating a new equal content type. Lucky me it wasn't too late. The problem was because something in a migration